# Unable to send command to newly created screen?

Tags: centos, shell, centos6, dedicated-server, gnu-screen

```
screen -dmS SIEGE_01 
sleep 1
screen -S SIEGE_01 -X stuff "cd /home/ss12036/ImpulseNetwork/Servers/SIEGE_01/"`echo -ne '\015'`
sleep 1
screen -S SIEGE_01 -X stuff "sh Start.sh"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

There is my code. This is a sh script that will be running on machine restart. For whatever reason, from line 3 and beyond the commands don't appear to be sent to the screen. What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to select a window to stuff the command in using `-p #` eg

```
screen -S SIEGE_01 -p 0 -X stuff "cd /home/ss12036/ImpulseNetwork/Servers/SIEGE_01/"`echo -ne '\015'`
```

to send it to the first window (0).

Also if this is a bash script just use

```
screen -S SIEGE_01 -p 0 -X stuff "cd /home/ss12036/ImpulseNetwork/Servers/SIEGE_01/
"
```

to get the carriage return in the `stuff` command.